# How to use gitlab-ci to manage test/construction of interdependent wheels

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-wheel

I have 3 python packages `proj1`, `proj12` and `proj13`. Both `proj12` and
`proj13` depend on `proj1` (with `from proj1.xxx import yyy`).

The 3 projects are on a private gitlab instance, each one has it's own `.gitlab-ci`.

In **proj1** `http://gitlab.me.com/group/proj1/.gitlab-ci.yml` we run unittest
and create a wheel exposed as an artifact::

```
# http://gitlab.me.com/group/proj1/.gitlab-ci.yml
image: python:2
mytest:
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - dist
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy; apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python setup.py test
  - python setup.py bdist_wheel
look:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - ls -lah dist
```

For **proj12** and **proj13** in e.g.
`http://gitlab.me.com/group/proj12/.gitlab-ci.yml` we would like to run tests
too, but I need to install `proj1` wheel to make it run.

All 3 projects are in the same gitlab private group.

What is the *gitlab* way to do this ?

- to pass the `proj1` wheel to the `proj12` with an [artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts)

  - in this case I don't know how to call/get the artifact in
    `http://gitlab.me.com/group/proj12/.gitlab-ci.yml` ? It's the same gitlab, the
    same group, but a different project.
- Use a gitlab *Secret Variable* to store [ssh_keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/ssh_keys/README.html) to clone `proj2` in `proj12/.gitlab-ci.yml` ?

  - related to https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4194
  - this does not take benefit of the fact that `proj1`, `proj12` and
    `proj13` are in the same gitlab and same group, the person who do the build
    for one project as credentials to do the others. All 3 are connected by the user private token.

I try to avoid to have to deploy devpi or pypiserver like solutions.

So I'm looking on what to write in the **proj12** `.gitlab-ci.yml` to get the 
`dist/proj1-0.42-py2-none-any.whl` wheel from the proj1 precedent build::

```
# http://gitlab.me.com/group/proj12/.gitlab-ci.yml
image: python:2
mytest12:
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy; apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install .
  - => some way here to get the proj1 wheel 
  - pip install proj1-0.42-py2-none-any.whl
  - python setup.py test
```

Links related to our issue:

- Allow access to build artifacts by using restricted access tokens https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19628
- "People need to be able to share links to artifacts based on a git ref (branch, tag, etc.), without knowing a specific build ID https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4255
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/ci/builds.html#upload-artifacts-to-build
- download-the-artifacts-file https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/builds.html#download-the-artifacts-file https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22957

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways you can do it:

- [Pass the object from previous build using the artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts) (works inside the same project only)
- Build a docker image with your packages pre-installed in a git job, store it in the in-built registry and use that to run build in your other projects.
- Clone the repository

I would advise passing as an artifact since then you will have it build exactly in the pipeline you are running. As for the cloning, AFAIK you don't need any workaround when cloning submodules but for cloning other repositories I would go with ssh deploy key as it's connected with a repo and not a user like the private token.

Comment: I've impacted my question with your comments, I doesn't know that we can use an artifact created in the build of one project in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` of some other gitlab project.

Comment: @user3313834 You supply the artifact as a path, it's avaiable in the same path in your next build. You path is dist so just do `ls dist` as the first step in your next build and you will see it.

Comment: Yes I've read really carefully the artifact gitlab documentation, artifact are  in the path **of the same container** accessible only by a job of the **same** gitlab-ci.yml in the same project. We need the artifact created in proj1 accessible in the proj12, a different gitlab project, a different git repository. I probably miss something but the documentation you point share artifact with a job of the same project.

Comment: @user3313834 Aaaah, I missed the part about the same project. Correct. Though that reminds me I forgot about custom docker containers.